# Find row number is a large pandas dataframe is very slow using np.where

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to find the row number of a dataframe having 55k rows. I am having multiple index and hence i tried to search using np.where. But this is very very slow. Is there a better solution to achieve in less than a millisecond. I tried loc, iloc but seems of not better options.

```
lprowcount = np.where(dfreglist['lineports'] == lineport)[0]
```

Also any best method to locate and update a row in a large dataframe other loc, iloc methods.

Comment: How about `(dfreglist['lineports'] == lineport).idxmax()`?

Comment: Hi coldspeed, thank you for your comment, but lprowcount = (dfreglist['lineports'] == lineport).idxmax() still having the same slowness.

Comment: What about `(dfreglist['lineports'].values == lineport).argmax()`?

Comment: argmax is much better than idxmax and got great improvement, but still slower than the requirement. Thanks for your support.